# Usage of exists and not exists in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, exists, pgadmin-4, not-exists

SQL code snippet #1:

```
select *  
from customer 
where exists (select null) 
order by residence desc;
```

SQL code snippet #2:

```
select customer_id, customer_name  
from customer
where exists (select customer_id 
              from customer 
              where residence = 'los angeles'
                and age > 20 and age < 40);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGgDi.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caDtE.png)

Both of the queries return all the rows in the table. I don't understand the difference. Can someone please explain why this is?

Also please explain what do `exists` and `not exists` do in short.

Thank you

Comment: > both of the above query returns all the rows in the record. ... ? Please provide examples and data sample.

Comment: i have attached the result sets of both query. please go through it and see whether u can help me.                
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the subquery returns at least one row, the result of EXISTS is true. In case the subquery returns no row, the result is of EXISTS is false.

https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-exists/

Both sequeries retuns at least 1 row and there is no filter on the main query, so both main query return all rows

- selec null -> 1 row
- select customer_id
  from customer
  where residence = 'los angeles'
  and age > 20 and age < 40
  -> some rows

If you want to select a subset, just use where in your main query, no need to use exits.

Comment: So using exists won't filter the record if exists is true?!! Thank you

Comment: Correct, where is enough (having if you use group).

Comment: ERROR:  column "purchase_rate" cannot be cast automatically to type integer HINT:  You might need to specify "USING purchase_rate::integer".

i tried to change the datatype . but came up with this error 

Please explain how to resolve this

Comment: Don't mix your questions, it'll be difficult to follow open a new post.

Comment: @Dri372 . . . As one additional note:  I strongly recommend not using `SELECT NULL` with `EXISTS`, precisely because of the confusing of "NULL" versus "No rows".  Plus, `SELECT 1` is easier to type.